# How to save strings to SPECIFIC location in p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, string, processing, p5.js

Here I have a code that I was playing around with.
It loads a string within my file and saves an unimportant one.

```
var file = "1";
var result;
var meString;
var splitMeString;

function preload() {
  result = loadStrings("assets/save/"+file+".txt");
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000,650);
}

function draw() {
    meString = result+'';
    splitMeString = splitTokens(meString, ',');
    text(meString,20,20);
    console.log(splitMeString[2]);
}

function mousePressed(){
    saveStrings("happy");
}
```

but how would I save a string to a specific location? Say I wanted to overwrite the file ("file")?

Answer (score 1):

Questions like these are best answered by looking in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveStrings).

According to the reference, the `saveStrings()` function can take three arguments:

> Syntax
>
> ```
> saveStrings(list,filename,[extension])
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> - `list`  String[]: string array to be written
> - `filename`  String: filename for output
> - `extension` String: the filename's extension

So it sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
saveStrings(yourArray, "file", "txt");
```

Also note that the third argument is optional, so this should also work:

```
saveStrings(yourArray, "file");
```

Comment: would the file extenstion be relative to the folder it is in? or would it be the full tree?                    
result = loadStrings("assets/save/"+file+".txt");
         result only used the folder

Comment: also i saw it and assumed extension meant .txt .doc .rtf and stuff

Comment: In case my question wasnt clear I am looking for a way to either move or download a file to a specific location is this possible in p5.js/javascript? thanks.

Comment: This answer doesn't help please don't redirect me to this one. I appreciate your having tried but I still need a new answer

Answer (score 0):

If you use the functions `storeItem()` and `getItem()` you can save strings to your program, this won't save it to a specific file embedded in your code but it will save it to your code. You can call whatever you stored in `storeItem()` with `getItem()`even after you close out of the tab. If you need any more info on it you can find it on the reference page [here.](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/storeItem) 
Hope this helps!