# How to select save location for saveStrings()

Tags: javascript, html, string, processing, p5.js

Here I have a code that I was playing around with. It loads a string within my file and saves an unimportant one.
this is p5.js
p5.js.org

```
var file = "1";
var result;
var meString;
var splitMeString;

function preload() {
  result = loadStrings("assets/save/"+file+".txt");
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000,650);
}

function draw() {
    meString = result+'';
    splitMeString = splitTokens(meString, ',');
    text(meString,20,20);
    console.log(splitMeString[2]);
}

function mousePressed(){
    saveStrings("happy");
}
```

but how would I save a string to a specific location? Say I wanted to overwrite the file ("file")?

Comment: _but how would I save a string to a specific location?_ -- You have two choices that both require a server-side solution too: 1. upload the file via  an HTML Form; 2. Send the data via an AJAX request. The server-side part of the solution would then save the file to the file system.

Comment: Are you trying to save this file to the user's computer, or to a location on your server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save strings to SPECIFIC location in p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282600/how-to-save-strings-to-specific-location-in-p5-js)

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282600/how-to-save-strings-to-specific-location-in-p5-js)?

Comment: Nobody answered my last one...(you werent responding) I couldnt find a bump feature
ANS to first comment: Both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just overwrite arbitrary files from JavaScript.

Like I mentioned in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50282839/873165), the best way to answer this type of question is by looking at [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).

Check out the `save()` function, which shows a prompt that allows the user to choose a download location.

But if you're trying to download the file to a specific location and overwrite a user's existing files, this can't be done from JavaScript for security reasons. Imagine if every website you visited was allowed to overwrite your files.

Comment: cool thanks for the help. Lets say that Im hosting on itch.io could it overwrite its own files? This may be a question for itch.io but if itch doesnt block it would you happen to know the syntax?

Comment: @J.Doe You probably would be better off using cookies or local storage rather than trying to download a file.

Comment: wouldnt that be deleted when the user resets his history?

Comment: @J.Doe As a web application you're at the mercy of the user. If you want to save the file in a way the user can't delete, you're going to have to save it to a server that you have control over. There is no way to create a file that the user can't delete from JavaScript.

Comment: so could i set up an sql server then get data from there using p5.js?

Comment: @J.Doe Sure, that's one option.

Comment: had a hard time figuring out how that works its not a code error so can i still post a question about it?

Comment: @J.Doe You can post anything you want, but keep in mind that broad questions like "how do I do this" are usually closed as off-topic.